# PHP custom *.ini file

Tags: php, ini

Does anyone know how to use a custom $config file? I know ZF and other frameworks such as CakePHP use a custom application.ini file to define application constant variables, environments etc. but how to add a such file and access it's values inside an application built with pure PHP no frameworks.

Answer (score 5):

Like for almost anything, there already is a function in PHP to do that: [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it helped me to solve my problem, but what I would also like to do is to use a custom php.ini file or create a custom one in order to override some values from php.ini. I know I could use `ini_set()`, but I want to change the PHP session name so I will not have to set `ini_set(session.name)` on each page where I use `session_start()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the contents of custom ini files with the [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function. It will return an associative array representing the settings specified in the file.